# pcscd unix domain socket forwarding

Tags: ssh-tunneling, unix-sockets, smartcard

I want to forward smart card request to a pc where smart card is connected but am unable to forward socket via ssh source : 10.169.213.211(server) destination : 10.169.41.124(client) what I attempt to achieve --> [in this link](https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2022/02/one-smart-card-reader-accessible-from.html)

some of the debug message are removed intentionally to follow the stack overflow rules.

```
user_id@hostname:~/samba/views/socket$ ssh -vvv -N -L/tmp/pcscd.comm:/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm -o StreamLocalBindUnlink=yes -o ClearAllForwardings=yes 10.169.213.211
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 10.169.213.211 ([10.169.213.211]:22).
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
```

Edit: Found answer in the [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/127794/forward-local-port-or-socket-file-to-remote-socket-file) page by @ijk.

Comment: I think the link to what you wanted to achieve did not get correctly included in your question! Could you fix that?

Comment: @I've added the link but finally got this setup working by using this link. https://serverfault.com/questions/127794/forward-local-port-or-socket-file-to-remote-socket-file. But I still wonder why it didn't work with ssh but only with socat.

Comment: feel free to edit your question to reflect that!